# Disable Excel 2013 cell animation

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-office-2013

When clicking into a cell of a Excel 2013 sheet, the green border of the cell is animated while moving from the current cell to the new one.

This is really disturbing. **How can I disable this animation?**

Comment: I instantly wanted to disable this when I experienced it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is a registry setting that allows you to disable **all animations across Office 2013** (thus not affecting other programs). It is explained in simple terms here: [[Tip] Improve Microsoft Office 2013 Performance by Disabling Unnecessary Animations](http://www.askvg.com/tip-improve-microsoft-office-2013-performance-by-disabling-unnecessary-animations). There's a download at the end of the post with the corresponding `.reg` files to enable or disable animations; just double click on the "disable animations" one.

In summary:

- create the following key in the registry if it does not exist yet: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Graphics`
- create a new DWORD `DisableAnimations` in that key and set its value to 1

There's no way to selectively disable some of Office 2013 animations;
it's an all-or-nothing proposition. [sotong's answer](https://superuser.com/a/548813/354511) to this question disables **all animations across Windows**.

**EDIT**

For those who don't have access to the `regedit` UI due to user privileges, this can also be done from the command line. Use <kbd>[image] (Win)</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, run <kbd>cmd</kbd> then paste in for Office 2013:

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Graphics ^
/v DisableAnimations /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

For Office 2016:

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Graphics ^
/v DisableAnimations /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

(all on one line).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I can't see the folder "Graphics" in my registry (Win8), but would be the better solution for the issue.

Comment: You may have to create it - I don't remember how it was. Have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, after adding the key `Graphics`and then the DWORD `DisableAnimations` the Animations are gone. So this is even the better answer for that issue. Thanks

Comment: FYI I just ran the .reg file from the link I posted on a Win8 x64/Office 2013 x86 machine and it worked.

Comment: Is the DWORD named `DisableAnimations` (plural) or `DisableAnimation` (singular)? See http://www.howtogeek.com/161826/how-to-disable-the-typing-animation-feature-in-office-2013/.

Comment: I have it in plural. According to the person who first published the fix (@rafael-rivera), it's plural. (http://withinwindows.com/2012/07/21/disabling-animations-in-office-2013)

Comment: Nice tip. Worked for me too +1

Comment: I'm on a computer where I'm blocked from using regedit. Solved by running `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Graphics" /v DisableAnimations /t REG_DWORD /d 1` from the command line. Does the same thing but without the regedit UI.

Comment: @ivarni I would consider that worthy of a new answer, or at least promotion to part of the main answer.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to turn off animations in Office 2013, which does NOT involve going into the registry, is as follows (quoted from Excel 2013 built-in help):

"Turn off Office animations

Office 2013 is the first release to use hardware acceleration throughout the user experience to deliver beautiful, fluid animations. But if you use your computer without a display or just prefer to block unnecessary animations, you have the choice to turn them off.

1.Open the Ease of Access Center (shown below) by pressing the Windows logo key + U.

2.Under Explore all settings, click Use the computer without a display.

3.Under Adjust time limits and flashing visuals, click Turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible).

4.Click OK."

Comment: This assumes Hardware Acceleration is only used for the animations. I'm concerned this setting might affect other aspects too.

Comment: Certainly a great alternative, as it doesn't involve admin authority and can be easily done in a workplace setting.

Answer (score 6):

You can turn off the animation by:

Control panel > System and security > System > Advanced system settings (in upper-left side) > Advanced tab > Settings in Performance box > Visual effects tab:

Uncheck the "Animate controls and elements inside windows."

Comment: Remark from user s_a: This disables all animations across windows (which is in my opinion not a bad thing)

Answer (score 2):

Hate that as well.

It appears to be a global setting unfortunately. You can disable it by going to Control Panel, Ease of Access Center, then click Make it easier to focus on tasks, and tick Turn off unnecessary animations. It will disable many other Windows animations though.

Comment: Please notice it is NOT a global setting (though you can of course disable all animations in windows).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution:

Excel 2013> Options> Advanced > Display> DISABLE Hardware Graphics Acceleration.

Comment: That's not an appropriate solution for disabling a single animation.

Comment: I've had this flag set for ages and this did not disable the animation described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following text in the notepad and rename the file as .reg  and then open the and merge the entry.

----------------- Copy text below ------------

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Graphics]
"DisableAnimations"=dword:00000001

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 7, click on the Start icon and type this:
"turn off unnecessary animations"

Then check the box by "turn off unnecessary animations" on the following screen.