# Excel 365 slow keyboard shortcuts

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm an experienced Microsoft Excel user and I've always loved the software in the past, when I used Excel 2007. One of the best things I liked about Excel 2007 was how I could do everything on the keyboard at a much higher speed than I could with the mouse.

However now in my new office I am using Excel 365, and it is extremely slow when I do keyboard shortcuts. For example, Paste Values is ALT-H-V-V, which executes instantly as fast as I can type it (a split second) in Excel 2007, but in Excel 365 it takes about 3-5 seconds to slowly display all the "letters" over the top tab and ribbon. This slows me down by multiples, and in this way Excel 365 was a severe downgrade for me.

Since I cannot exchange my 365 for 2007, I would like to ask for help on how to resolve this issue. I've tried all the things other forums and posts have recommended - disabling Tool Tips, changing the "hardware graphics accelerator option" under File - Options - Advanced, disabling the animations and even something I had to do on the Control Panel. Nothing works.

Appreciate any suggestions you might have.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 

Yes - the shortcuts which get slow are the ALT- shortcuts, which go through the tabs and ribbons at the top of the window. How do I get rid of the rendering? It seems to me that the problem is because Excel 365 is doing some extra (unnecessary) things when I use keyboard shortcuts. I want to disable those unnecessary things that it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using shortcuts that visually go through the ribbon, turn off animations for all of office 2013 -

> 1. create the following key in the registry if it does not exist yet: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Graphics
> 2. create a new DWORD DisableAnimations in that key and set its value to 1

[source](https://superuser.com/questions/547832/disable-excel-2013-cell-animation)

Answer (score 0):

Registry Editor is a much better way.

Other way is changing BIOS settings.

"The issue is that chances are your company issued laptop has very aggressive default settings for saving battery in your BIOs. What happens every time you press alt to conjure up the shortcuts is that your processor spins up like crazy, not sure why it needs to but that's what happens. And for my computer's BIOs, there were two settings that intentionally throttle my processor's speed:
1) SpeedStep and
2) C-State.

Just disable both of them, or any other options that are meant to slow down your processor, and THIS PROBLEM WILL BE GONE FOREVER."

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/slow-alt-key-shortcuts-on-excel-and-word/4b8c23e6-bd7e-401f-92a2-3df39d54604a?auth=1