# Slow shortcuts on Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have just installed excel 2016 on my computer for work. I am processing a fairly average data set. However, I am finding the keyboard shortcuts much slower than in Excel 2013.

For example, when I use "ALT-A-T" to create filters, the workbook takes 3-5 seconds to process. Alternatively, when I simply press the button in the ribbon, the workbook responds instantly.

I already turned off cursor animations in the OPTIONS > ADVANCED > GENERAL settings. Is there any other way to turn off whatever extraneous activity is happening in the background?

Thanks!
Lisa

Comment: You should be able to comment now

Answer (score 1):

If you're using shortcuts that visually go through the ribbon, turn off animations for all of office 2016 -

> 1. create the following key in the registry if it does not exist yet: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Graphics
> 2. create a new DWORD DisableAnimations in that key and set its value to 1

It went from [15.0](https://superuser.com/questions/818741/excel-365-slow-keyboard-shortcuts) to 16.0