# Enable Office 2013 transition animations

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-office-2013

I just upgraded from Office 2010 to 2013, and I can't see the transition animations I was expecting (when moving the cell selector in Excel, when the cursor blinks in Word, etc.).

Lots of information around about turning this *off*, but apparently no one but me has it off and wants to turn it on... Any ideas?

I already made sure that the solutions to turn *off* animations in this thread are *not* in effect: [Disable Excel 2013 cell animation](https://superuser.com/questions/547832/disable-excel-2013-cell-animation)